# Laravel- Eloquent many to many get unattached data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `User`, `Shop` and `Product` model on my app. And relationship like this:

User

```
public function products(){
   return $this->hasMany("App\Product");
}
public function shops(){
   return $this->hasMany("App\Shop");
}
```

Shop

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
}
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Product");
}
```

Product

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function shops(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Shop");
}
```

So, user can add **Products** and **Shops** and then attach a product to many shop. Now I can get all of the attached shops by `$product->shops` on `product` page and auth users all shop by `auth()->user()->shops`. Actually, I want to show the auth users shop that is not attached to this `Product` on the `Product` page. According to Laravel documentation, I write some code but for some reason it doesn't work. My code is :

```
auth()->user()->shops()->whereDoesntHave('products', function (Builder $query) {
                                $query->where('id','!=', $product->id);
                            })->get();
```

Error:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It *should* work if you change `function (Builder $query)` to simply `function ($query)`. Also, include `use($product)` so that `$product->id` is accessible in scope. So altogether: `->whereDoesntHave(function($query) use($product){ ... })->get()`

Comment: Hi @TimLewis It's working now. Please explain the first change as an answer, I want to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer here.

Firstly, the usage of `function(Builder $query)` is targeting the incorrect version of `Builder` (likely a namespacing issue), so simply removing `Builder` from the function should allow it to resolve.

Secondly, to use `$product` in scope of the new function, it needs to be passed use `use($product)`, otherwise you'll get an `Undefined variable $product` error.

Altogether, the new function should look like this:

```
auth()->user()->shops()->whereDoesntHave('products', function ($query) use($product) {
  $query->where('id','!=', $product->id);
})->get();
```